# Why is GCP disk type a resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Why disk type in gcp (google cloud platform) is a resource that can be accessed using project id and zone instead of just being a constant like standard persistent, ssd persistent and ssd local?

Answer (score 1):

[disk types](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disk-types/) are being handled as a resource, because the output of `gcloud compute disk-types list` is not what one would expect - but the available disk types per zone (which is a resource):

```
NAME         ZONE                       VALID_DISK_SIZES
local-ssd    europe-west3-b             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west3-b             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west3-b             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west3-c             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west3-c             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west3-c             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east2-c               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east2-c               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east2-c               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west3-a             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west3-a             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west3-a             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west2-c             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west2-c             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west2-c             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-northeast1-b          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-northeast1-b          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-northeast1-b          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west2-c                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west2-c                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west2-c                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west1-d             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west1-d             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west1-d             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east1-a               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east1-a               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east1-a               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east1-b               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east1-b               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east1-b               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east1-c               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east1-c               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east1-c               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west1-b                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west1-b                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west1-b                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west1-c                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west1-c                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west1-c                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west1-b             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west1-b             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west1-b             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west1-c             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west1-c             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west1-c             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west2-a                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west2-a                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west2-a                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    southamerica-east1-c       375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       southamerica-east1-c       10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  southamerica-east1-c       10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    southamerica-east1-b       375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       southamerica-east1-b       10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  southamerica-east1-b       10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west2-b             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west2-b             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west2-b             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west2-a             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west2-a             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west2-a             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-north1-b            375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-north1-b            10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-north1-b            10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-north1-a            375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-north1-a            10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-north1-a            10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-north1-c            375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-north1-c            10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-north1-c            10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east2-a               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east2-a               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east2-a               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    southamerica-east1-a       375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       southamerica-east1-a       10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  southamerica-east1-a       10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-southeast1-c          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-southeast1-c          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-southeast1-c          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east1-c                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east1-c                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east1-c                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east1-b                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east1-b                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east1-b                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    australia-southeast1-a     375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       australia-southeast1-a     10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  australia-southeast1-a     10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-northeast1-c          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-northeast1-c          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-northeast1-c          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-southeast1-b          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-southeast1-b          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-southeast1-b          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-southeast1-a          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-southeast1-a          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-southeast1-a          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-east2-b               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-east2-b               10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-east2-b               10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    australia-southeast1-c     375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       australia-southeast1-c     10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  australia-southeast1-c     10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-central1-a              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-central1-a              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-central1-a              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-south1-b              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-south1-b              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-south1-b              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-central1-c              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-central1-c              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-central1-c              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-central1-b              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-central1-b              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-central1-b              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-northeast1-a          375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-northeast1-a          10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-northeast1-a          10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east1-d                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east1-d                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east1-d                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-central1-f              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-central1-f              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-central1-f              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    northamerica-northeast1-c  375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       northamerica-northeast1-c  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  northamerica-northeast1-c  10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west1-a                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west1-a                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west1-a                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east4-a                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east4-a                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east4-a                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-south1-c              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-south1-c              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-south1-c              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east4-c                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east4-c                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east4-c                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-east4-b                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-east4-b                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-east4-b                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west4-a             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west4-a             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west4-a             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west4-c             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west4-c             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west4-c             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    europe-west4-b             375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       europe-west4-b             10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  europe-west4-b             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    asia-south1-a              375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       asia-south1-a              10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  asia-south1-a              10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    northamerica-northeast1-a  375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       northamerica-northeast1-a  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  northamerica-northeast1-a  10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    australia-southeast1-b     375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       australia-southeast1-b     10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  australia-southeast1-b     10GB-65536GB
local-ssd                               375GB-375GB
pd-ssd                                  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard                             10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    us-west2-b                 375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       us-west2-b                 10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  us-west2-b                 10GB-65536GB
local-ssd    northamerica-northeast1-b  375GB-375GB
pd-ssd       northamerica-northeast1-b  10GB-65536GB
pd-standard  northamerica-northeast1-b  10GB-65536GB
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinZeitler. I can see the valid_disk_sizes to be changing across the zones, so it makes sense.  Is it possible that some zone doesn't support a disk type?Its not evident in the list.

Comment: @Mugdha they all seem to offer the same capacities (while available). I'd rather wonder about all the entries which do not list any zone. can also run `gcloud compute disk-types describe local-ssd --zone=europe-west3-b` ...which then also has a link to the default project.

Comment: @Mugdha Is the question you are asking "Why are disk types resources?" or is your question "Why are disk types specific to a zone or region?" If it is the second one, then the reason they are listed by zone is because not every disk type is necessarily available in every Google location. Some services are only available in specific regions.

Comment: If a "disk type" was not a Resource, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/) (GCP) offers several [storage options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/):

- [Zonal standard persistent disk and Zonal SSD persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs)
- [Regional persistent disk and regional SSD persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#repds)
- [Local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds)
- [Cloud storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#gcsbuckets)

More information: [Global, Regional and Zonal Resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources)

The **zonal** disk services (zonal PD and zonal SSD) provide a block storage option that is reliable within a single zone.

The **regional** disk services (regional PD and regional SSD) provide a block storage option that is replicated in two different zones, so it's resilient to zone failure.

The **local** option (local SSD) is a great option for fast, temporary block storage, and doesn't provide any replication.

The **cloud storage buckets** option uses Google's s3-like object storage service, GCS.

You can create disk resources that meet the capacity, performance, and reliability requirements of your application. Disk resources you create are associated with the zones or regions where they are created and are available to virtual machines created in the same project and locality.

Comment: Hi @lukwam, may be my question wasn't clear enough. I was referring to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/diskTypes

Comment: @Mugdha I'm not sure I understand. The link you shared shows how the compute REST API works. It describes the resources used by the API. The reason that disk types are a resource here is that this particular API you linked to is specifically geared towards that particular sort of object, a Disk Type, which is a resource in the context of a REST API.  More on REST resources here: https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html. Each API method works with a different type of resource, but the diskTypes endpoint specifically works with Disk Type Resources.